# Why directive is avaible in $rootScope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

it's not kind of problem right now, but it made me curious a bit.

I have a simple directive, which - I don't know why - is avaible inside $rootScope.

> **JAVASCRIPT:**

```
(function(){

  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['m.directives']);

    app.run(function($rootScope){
    console.log($rootScope);
  });

  angular.module('m.directives', [])
  .directive('mUserSidebar', mUserSidebarDirective);

  function mUserSidebarDirective() {

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      template: "<p>{{userSidebar.date | date : 'HH:mm'}}</p>",
      controller: mUserSidebarController,
      controllerAs: 'userSidebar'
    };
  };

  mUserSidebarController.$inject = ['$interval'];

  function mUserSidebarController($interval) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.date = new Date();

    vm.logOut = function(){
      console.log('log out');
    }

    function refreshDate(){

      $interval(function(){
        vm.date = new Date();
      }, 1000);
    }

     refreshDate();
    }
})();
```

> **HTML:**

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
    <p style="font-weight: bold"> directive: </p>
    <div data-m-user-sidebar></div>
    <p style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 50px">rootScope</p>
    <div>{{$root.userSidebar}}</div>
</div>
```

> **EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/y8qgmhcw/

---

What's more interesting, if I'll use it along with ui-router and I place the directive:

1) **Inside *ui-view***: The directive is not avaible in $rootScope

2) **Outside *ui-view***: It's avaible in $rootScope

---

So. The questions are:

*1) Why it happens like that?*

*2) Is it my fault ? Did I missed something? :-)*

*3) Can I do anything to ommit this behaviour?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Figured it out!**

As in my directive definition object "scope" variable was undefinied, my directive used its parent scope ($rootScope).

So, **DDO** should look like:

```
function mUserSidebarDirective() {

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      scope: true,
      template: "<p>{{userSidebar.date | date : 'HH:mm'}}</p>",
      controller: mUserSidebarController,
      controllerAs: 'userSidebar'
    };
  };
```

> **FIXED:** http://jsfiddle.net/y8qgmhcw/1/